# flutter build ios command is always stucked at └─Compiling, linking and signing... ⣯

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, firebase

```
Running pod install...                                           2,087ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                            ⣻
```

flutter build ios command is always stuck at └─Compiling, linking, and signing... ⣯

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**make a backup of the project and try this**

1. delete iOS folder
2. flutter create (new project with same name)
3. copy iOS folder to the replace deleted file
4. flutter clean
5. flutter run

Answer (score 0):

1. new create a flutter
2. copy lib and assent file
3. add dependencies
4. flutter ios build

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same issue after running `flutter build ipa`. I honestly do not know what caused the problem.

However, killing the process, restarting my computer, and running the process again seemed to have fixed the issue for me.